# Transform ICollection .toDictionary() c#

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-4, dictionary

I am in a project that uses MVC4 with EntityFramework.

In my C# code I access the database with a simple query that returns a package. Now a package has a list of items, and I need a dictionary with the Id and Name of those items. I achieve the following using this code:

```
Package pkg = (from aPkg in DB.Packages where aPkg.PackageId == id 
    select aPkg).First();

Dictionary<int, string> materials = new Dictionary<int,string>();

foreach(Material mat in pkg.Materials){
    materials.Add(mat.MaterialId, mat.Label);
}
```

However this is quite verbose, and I noticed that there is another function that I can use: `pkg.Materials.toDictionary<tKey, tElement>()`.

Unfortunatly, even after checking the official documentation, I cannot understand how to use this function to achieve the same goal in a less verbose way. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548657(v=vs.100).aspx), you have to provide two `Func<TSource, TResult>` objects, to return the values that are going to be used for key and value of your dictionary elements.

```
var materials = pkg.Materials.ToDictionary(x => x.MaterialId, x => x.Label);
```

Still be careful that MaterialId is unique, otherwise the ToDictionary extension method (and your code) will crash.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
var dictionary = pkg.Materials.ToDictionary(id => id.MaterialId, l => l.Label);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use ToDictionary method in this way:

```
pkg.Materials.ToDictionary(x => x.MaterialId, x => x.Label);
```